# Align a CSS toggle with text

Tags: html, css, dom

I have some text and a toggle that is themed with CSS.  I'd like the toggle to be vertically aligned with the text.  I've tried a several ways without any luck.  Appreciate any help you can give me.  Thanks!

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #651C0C;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h5>Reveal Links <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" onchange="v30showall(this)"><div class="slider round"></div></label></h5>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use the  `vertical-align:middle;` rule

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

> The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
  vertical-align:middle; /* added */
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #651C0C;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h5>Reveal Links <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" onchange="v30showall(this)"><div class="slider round"></div></label></h5>
```

Comment: Perfect and easy fix.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend giving the `Reveal Link` its own container (in this case a `<span>`), and floating both of those to the left, rather than using `display: inline-block` on the `.switch`:

```css
h5 span {
  float: left;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #651C0C;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h5>
  <span>Reveal Links</span>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="v30showall(this)">
    <div class="slider round"></div>
   </label>
</h5>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  The trouble here would be I also want them centered.  I should of mentioned that in the question.